# Multiple like with where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I want to build a sql query with multiple like with case statement. Here is my sql query. Case statement is used to make sure, Is this request from Web Site or Mobile, If request is from website then case statement will work other wise no need.

Here is Likes:

```
i.ItemNumber like '%-NLA' or 
i.ItemNumber like '%-NLA DEL' or 
i.ItemNumber like '%-NLAmod'
```

Please help me out.

```
select count(p.SkuID) as Total from Product p (nolock)
join items i (nolock) on p.SkuID = i.SkuID
join #TempProductLine pl (nolock) on i.ProductLineID = pl.ProductLineID where p.ProductID = @ParentId and i.IsSelling = 1 and
case when @IsWebSite = 1 then
    PATINDEX ('%-NLA DEL',i.ItemNumber) 
end = 0
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server to me, yet you've tagged with 2 other databases.  Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: I removed them all. Add one tag back, the one for the dbms used.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using SIMILAR TO would work ?

```
SELECT * from table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '(AAA|BBB|CCC)%';
```

So combine it like `i.ItemNumber SIMILAR TO '%(-NLA|-NLA DEL|-NLAmod)';`

Some other things you may want to try:

```
LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%-NLA','%-NLA DEL','%-NLAmod'])
```

Comment: I also tried, this thing is not working. Thanks @Aakash Verma

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select count(p.SkuID) as Total from Product p (nolock)
join items i (nolock) on p.SkuID = i.SkuID
join #TempProductLine pl (nolock) on i.ProductLineID = pl.ProductLineID   where 
p.ProductID = @ParentId and i.IsSelling = 1 and
i.ItemNumber like '%' + 
case 
when @IsWebSite = 1 then '-NLA'
when @IsWebSite = 2 then '-NLA DEL'
when @IsWebSite = 3 then '-NLAmod'
else '' end
```

or simply like this :

```
select count(p.SkuID) as Total from Product p (nolock)
join items i (nolock) on p.SkuID = i.SkuID
join #TempProductLine pl (nolock) on i.ProductLineID = pl.ProductLineID   where 
p.ProductID = @ParentId and i.IsSelling = 1 and
(
@IsWebSite = 1 and i.ItemNumber like '%-NLA' or
@IsWebSite = 2 and i.ItemNumber like '%-NLA DEL' or
@IsWebSite = 3 and i.ItemNumber like '%-NLAmod'
)
```

Comment: It doesn't full fill my requirement. so now i forward with Dynamic sql query. I  have **@IsWebSite bit** type, so it can not be 1,2 and 3.

Comment: AND? Modify my query i Will given an example... Or explain your data before AND after ;)